# Symfony 2 cache stuck after config change (FileLoaderException)

Tags: symfony, config

Very strange behavior in Sf2 here. I've try to change my config namespaces while i was refactoring code:

```
adadgio_rocket:
    foo: 'bar'
```

to something simple

```
adadgio:
    rocket: 'bar'
```

I have change my bundle DI Configuration nodes to reflect that change :

```
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('adadgio');
$rootNode->children()
    ->scalarNode('rocket')->end()
->end();
```

Now i have a `FileLoaderLoadException` still saying  able to load the configuration for `adadgio` but still finds the `adadgio_rocket` namespace (error results).

I tried to clear the cache thinking this was the issue, but of course, the symphony cache command issues the same error. And its still finds other config namespaces that were removes (and their declaration in the AppKernel as well).

[image]

Basically, everything is stuck now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that sort of stuff can happen. Simply delete the `app/cache/dev` directory and run `app/console cache:clear` again.

If it still doesn’t work, make 100% sure that there are no remainders in the config or referenced in other bundles. If unsure, check:

```
grep -ir adadgio app/config/ src/ vendor/
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be a issue of permission also. Give 777 permission to cache and use following to clear cache without warming up the cache:

```
app/console cache:clear --env=<your environment> --no-warmup
```

Comment: Done that. It does not change anything

Comment: then I think you really need to find the string and remove it from everywhere.